# Benefits of async and await for Console Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core

I know the benefits of using async and await for .NET Web API and Web Applications. I wanted to know what benefits it provide if I use it in my Console application.

Comment: That would depend on what you're doing in your console application. For a hello world - no, there is no benefit.

Comment: You get to write asynchronous code.

Comment: Honestly, not much. In web apps, it makes more sense as we have to serve more users with limited number of threads.

Comment: So async programming frees up threads when it's waiting for something long to return results. In web api and web application that thread can be used to process more incoming request. But what I am not understanding is how it will benefit my console application

Comment: Does your console application have useful work that can be done whilst you wait for long running I/O to complete? If so, it'll probably benefit. If not, then likely no. Which is *exactly the same situation* as other application types. As fredrik's first comment alluded to, however, it entirely depends on the nature of your specific console application. Don't assume that there's a *universal* benefit to be obtained.

Answer (score 1):

With `async`/`await`, you write less code, and your code will be more maintainable than using the previous asynchronous programming methods, such as using plain tasks. `async`/`await` is the newer replacement to BackgroundWorker, which has been used on WinForms applications.